# Búsqueda en un arreglo de cadenas

Tags: java, string, array

¿Cómo realizar la búsqueda de una palabra en un arreglo de tipo `String`?

Ejemplo:

```
String[] arreglo = { "David", "StackOverflow", "StackOverflow en español" };
String encuentrame = "StackOverflow";
arreglo.?; //¿qué hacer en este caso?
```

Comment: si buscas una palabra en una cadena usa, `varcadena.contains("palabra")` si quieres ignorar mayusculas y minusculas, usa `varcadena.toLowerCase().contains("palabra".toLowerCase())`

Comment: @rnd justo un ejemplo típico de lo que comenté en tu respuesta  en meta

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ¿pero puede editarse y acabar siendo una pregunta util para otros?

Comment: @rnd el punto es que han pasado 6 horas desde que el Op ha vuelto a entrar al sitio (redactó la pregunta y se fue hasta esperar una respuesta quizás?), la pregunta ha recibido votos negativos, alguien ha respondido y se le ha votado a favor y nadie ha editado la pregunta para que luzca de calidad para el sitio. Todo tal como te expliqué en mi comentario. Pasa en el sitio en inglés, pasa aquí y seguirá sucediendo sin importar cuánto queramos evitarlo.

Answer (score 5):

Si utilizas Java 8, la mejor opción es convertir tu arreglo a `Stream` vía `Arrays#stream` y realizar la búsqueda allí. La ventaja de esta alternativa es que soporta arreglos de datos primitivos.

Un ejemplo para tu caso sería el siguiente:

```
String[] arreglo = { "David", "StackOverflow", "StackOverflow en español" };
String encuentrame = "David";
String resultado = Arrays.stream(arreglo)
                         .filter(s -> s.equals(encuentrame))
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(null);
if (resultado != null) {
    System.out.println("Encontrado");
} else {
    System.out.println("No Encontrado");
}
```

Y si trabajases con un primitivo como `int`:

```
int[] arreglo = { 1, 2, 3};
int encuentrame = 3;
int resultado = Arrays.stream(arreglo)
                      .filter(x -> x == encuentrame)
                      .findFirst()
                      .orElse(-1);
if (resultado != -1) {
    System.out.println("Encontrado");
} else {
    System.out.println("No Encontrado");
}
```

Lo genial de utilizar `Stream`s es que puedes utilizar diferentes formas para identificar al elemento, no solo utilizando el método `equals`. Por ejemplo, puedes verificar si ambas palabras son iguales sin importar mayúsculas ni minúsculas de esta manera:

```
String[] arreglo = { "David", "StackOverflow", "StackOverflow en español" };
String encuentrame = "dAvId";
String resultado = Arrays.stream(arreglo)
                         .filter(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(encuentrame))
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(null);
if (resultado != null) {
    System.out.println("Encontrado");
} else {
    System.out.println("No Encontrado");
}
```

Si tu arreglo tiene muchos elementos y vas a buscar datos sobre él constantemente, sería mejor convertir los datos del arreglo en un `Set` (conjunto) implementado por `HashSet` y luego realizar las búsquedas siempre contra esta estructura. Las búsquedas contra un `HashSet` tienden a ser más veloces porque se hace uso del `hashCode` del elemento, reduciendo el tiempo de búsqueda a O(1) (asumiendo que hay pocas colisiones). Aquí un ejemplo:

```
String[] arreglo = { "David", "StackOverflow", "StackOverflow en español" };
Set<String> conjunto = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arreglo));
if (conjunto.contains(...)) {
}
```

Comment: recomendaría usar `encuentrame.equals(s)` en lugar de `s.equals(encuentrame)` para evitar NPEs. O, si `null` es un valor válido, `Objects.equals(s, encuentrame)`.

Comment: Usualmente la lista no deberia tener valores nulos mientras que `encuentrame` si puede serlo.

Answer (score 2):

Como complemento a las respuestas, existen varías formas para buscar en un arreglo de strings, por ejemplo la forma común:

```
public static boolean buscaString(String[] miarray, String valor) {
    for(String s: miarray){
        if(s.equals(valor))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usando [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html):

```
public static boolean buscaString(String[] miarray, String valor) {
    return Arrays.asList(miarray).contains(valor);
}
```

Como ya se comentó, esto no funciona para arrays de tipos primitivos.

Usando [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html):

```
public static boolean buscaString(String[] miarray, String valor) {
    Set<String> miSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(miarray));
    return miSet.contains(valor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convertirlo en una lista es la forma más sencilla de escribirlo:

```
    String[] arrayString = new String[]{"uno", "dos", "tres"};
    String cadenaBuscar = "tres";
    if(Arrays.asList(arrayString).contains(cadenaBuscar)) {
        System.out.println("Encontrado");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No encontrado");
    }
```

Esto no sólo funciona con `String`, también funciona con cualquier otro tipo de objeto (siempre que tenga implementado correctamente `equals` y `hashCode`). No funciona con arrays de tipos primitivos.

Comment: Mejor convertirlo a `Set` en lugar de lista. Otra opción es ordenarlo y aplicar búsqueda binaria, ambos métodos existen en la clase `Arrays`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ¿Qué método te permite convertir directamente un array en un set?

Comment: `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(...))`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no veo sentido a convertirlo primero a Lista y luego a Set, para eso lo dejamos simplemente en una lista. La única excepción sería si fueses a hacer bastantes comparaciones con el mismo array, entonces podría merecer la pena porque en un HashSet la búsqueda es más eficiente.

Comment: Dependiendo del tamaño del arreglo en realidad. Es más, desde Java 8 no tiene mucho sentido convertirlo a lista, sería más práctico y seguro convertirlo a `Stream` y aplicar el método `filter`